# Mensaje de espera mientras traigo los datos

Tags: reactjs

Tengo este componente en react para obtener algunos datos y volver a representar el estado. Hay un proceso en curso en el back-end, por lo que lleva unos segundos representar el estado.

¿Hay alguna forma de representar un mensaje de carga antes de que se procese el estado?

```
class TicketsContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: []
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL || 'https://localhost:5050';
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);


  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  /** de esta forma obtengo los datos */
  getData() {
    Axios.get(`${this.apiUrl}/agents`)
      .then(result => this.setState({ ...this.state, data: result.data }))
      .catch(error => alert(error.message));
  }

  /** Y de la siguiente forma muestro los datos en una tabla */
  render() {
    return {this.state.data.length && (
      <tbody className="list table-hover">
        {this.state.data.map((agent) => {
          return (
            <tr id={agent._id} onClick={() => this.handleRowClick(agent)}>
              <td className="">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-1 mr-3 xs">
                    <div class="avatar-table">
                      <img
                        src={avatar}
                        alt="..."
                        class="avatar-img rounded avatar-xs"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-auto mt-1">
                    {agent.firstName} {agent.lastName}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td className="">{agent.phone}</td>
              <td className="">{agent.email}</td>
              <td className="">{agent.agentType}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    )}
  }
}
```

Por ejemplo que en la tabla (o en lugar de la tabla) se muestre el mensaje : "Se estan cargando los datos"

Comment: Lo más más simple en este caso es que en lugar de usar una expresión AND, uses el operador ternario: `{this.state.data.length === 0 ? 'Tu mensaje de fallback' : (el JSX de tu tabla)`. Pero aunque ésta es la solución inmediata, me encantaría tomar tu código  (por su sencillez) como ejemplo de como se haría con hooks y con Suspense, me permitirías hacer la edición y poner entonces una respuesta más completa? Pido permiso porque aquí en el comentario ya te di la solución y tú podrías compartir por ti mismo la solución real y ganarte más puntos, pero además va un poco más allá de tu pregunta concr

Comment: No problema, puedes hacer de ella tuya si quieres. estoy aprendiendo y agradezco tu predisposición.

Comment: Perfecto, en un ratito más lo comparto completo, mientras puedes probar la solución simple que te di en el comentario. Sólo pasa tu expresión a una con operador ternario.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido de nuevo a StackOverflow en español, espero poder ayudarte, y te agradezco me permitas compartir que existe más de una solución al mismo requerimiento.

Para empezar, voy a simplificar un poco tu componente que está en una clase, para plantearlo como un componente funcional con hooks, ya que precisamente, disminuyen el boilerplate y abren muchas nuevas posibilidades.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function TicketsContainer ({ apiUrl, handleRowClick }) {
  const [ tickets, setTickets ] = useState([])

  /** con useEffect llamamos a la API, "efectuamos una acción" */
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(`${apiUrl}/agents`)
      .then(result => setTickets( result.data ))
      .catch(error => alert(error.message))
  }, []) /* dependencias === [], invoca efecto solo al montar el componente */

  return {tickets.length && (
      <tbody className="list table-hover">
        {tickets.map((agent) => {
          return (
            <tr id={agent._id} onClick={() => handleRowClick(agent)}>
              <td className="">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-1 mr-3 xs">
                    <div class="avatar-table">
                      <img
                        src={avatar}
                        alt="..."
                        class="avatar-img rounded avatar-xs"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-auto mt-1">
                    {agent.firstName} {agent.lastName}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td className="">{agent.phone}</td>
              <td className="">{agent.email}</td>
              <td className="">{agent.agentType}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>
    )}
}
```

Como puedes ver, estoy pasando la apiUrl y la función para manejar el click del agente, en los props del componente, la función de `handleClick` la puedes declarar en el mismo módulo, o dentro de la misma función. Por lo demás la lógica es idéntica. Los hooks que utilizamos son [useEffect](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) y [useState](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

¿Ahora, qué opciones tenemos para mostrar un mensaje de espera?

La primera y más sencilla es cambiar la expresión de `tickets.length && ${jsx}` a un operador ternario, comparando contra el tamaño del array de tickets, quedaría algo así:

```
return tickets.length === 0
  ? 'Por favor espere, cargando la lista de tickets'
  : {<tbody>...}
```

Había prometido en los comentarios, usar `Suspense`, pero por el momento, solo está en producción para componentes que se cargan en demanda con `React.lazy`. No obstante en un futuro próximo puede ser una solución aún más simple que manualmente verificar los datos que tenemos en el `state` de nuestro componente: https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html

No obstante veamos otra opción, manejar la carga de datos externos, y el manejo de error, con un patrón muy interesante y básico y que te permitirá hacer más *testeable* tus componentes. Es el simple patrón Contenedor - Presentación (o smart vs dumb).

En este separamos la lógica de recuperar datos, de la presentación, básicamente tu componente de presentación no sabe de donde le llegan los datos, o el mensaje de error, o la función que maneja el click a una fila, nada, solo recibe y presenta los datos y pasa los eventos a la función que maneja el dato, es pura vista.

Y por otra parte, tienes el contenedor, que maneja la lógica y las pasa a la presentación.

```js
function TicketsContainerHandleError ({ apiUrl }) {
  function handleRowClick (agent) {
    // useModal u otra mecanismo para manejar el detalle de un elemento
  }

  const [ tickets, setTickets ] = useState([])
  const [ error, setError ] = useState('')
  const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState('Por favor espere, cargando tickets')

  const retryFn = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    setError('')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(`${apiUrl}/agents`)
      .then(result => {
        setTickets( result.data )
        setLoading(false)
       })
      .catch(error => setError(error.message))
  }, [error])



  return (
    <TicketsView
      loading={loading}
      tickets={tickets}
      error={error}
      handleRowClick={handleRowClick}
      retryFn={retryFn}
    />
  )
}

function TicketsView ({ loading, tickets, error, handleRowClick, retryFn }) {
   if (loading) {
      return <div>{loading}</div>
   }
   if (error !== '') {
      return (
         <div className="errorRecover">
           <div className="errorMessage">{error}</div>
           <button onClick={() => retryFn()}>Puede intentar nuevamente</button>
         </div>
      )
   }
   return (<tbody className="list table-hover">
        {tickets.map((agent) => {
          return (
            <tr id={agent._id} onClick={() => handleRowClick(agent)}>
              <td className="">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-1 mr-3 xs">
                    <div class="avatar-table">
                      <img
                        src={avatar}
                        alt="..."
                        class="avatar-img rounded avatar-xs"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-auto mt-1">
                    {agent.firstName} {agent.lastName}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td className="">{agent.phone}</td>
              <td className="">{agent.email}</td>
              <td className="">{agent.agentType}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </tbody>)
}
```

El patrón presentación - contenedor, te permite sacar de la lógica de la vista, incluso mayor complejidad y manejar otros casos de la lógica de estado, por ejemplo hacer cancelable la promesa del fetch de Axios, u otras librerías, evitando así errores por pasar datos (se da el caso con `setState` en componentes de clase también) a componentes que ya fueron desmontados.